# Upgrading Hibernate 2.1.8 to Hibernate 3.6.10

Tags: java, hibernate

We are trying to upgrade a legacy application from Hibernate 2.1.8 to Hibernate 3.6.10. The application uses few classes written using hibernate 2.1.8 api to provide their own persistence mechanism. The problem is that Hibernate 3.6.10 does not have those api's functions anymore and hence we need to rewrite the classes. Can you help us in finding the appropriate matches in hibernate 3 for below :

HibernateProxyHelper.getLazyInitializer((HibernateProxy)object).isUninitialized()

You can see the code below

```
import java.util.Collection;
import net.sf.hibernate.HibernateException;
import net.sf.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection;
import net.sf.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy;
import net.sf.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxyHelper;
import com.******.component.AbstractComponent;
import com.******.****.persistence.ILazyInitializationProxyStrategy;
import com.******.****.persistence.PersistenceException;

/*
 *  Initialize Hibernate proxies
 */
public class HibernateLazyInitializationProxyStrategy extends AbstractComponent
    implements ILazyInitializationProxyStrategy {

/**
 * @return is the object an uninitialized hibernate proxy  
 */
public boolean isProxy(Object object) {
    return isObjectProxy(object) || isCollectionProxy(object);
}


public boolean isObjectProxy(Object object) {
    return object instanceof HibernateProxy && HibernateProxyHelper.getLazyInitializer((HibernateProxy)object).isUninitialized();
}


public boolean isCollectionProxy(Object object) {
    return object instanceof PersistentCollection && !((PersistentCollection)object).wasInitialized();
}
public Object initializeProxy(Object object) throws PersistenceException{
   Object returnValue = object;
    if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
       try {
        if (HibernateProxyHelper.getLazyInitializer((HibernateProxy)object).isUninitialized()) {
          HibernateProxyHelper.getLazyInitializer((HibernateProxy)object).initialize();
        }
        returnValue =  HibernateProxyHelper.getLazyInitializer((HibernateProxy)object).getImplementation();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           throw new PersistenceException(e);
        }  
    } else if(isCollectionProxy(object)) { 
        ((Collection)object).size();
    }
    return returnValue; 
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If there are only a few classes, why not reimplement them in [Hibernate with JPA](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html)? I think that would be easier?

Comment: Yes that would be the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Hibernate API (Not pure JPA) you can use the method [`Hibernate.isInitialized(java.lang.Object)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized(java.lang.Object))

If you can use JPA2 you can do it using PersistenceUnitUtil as below

```
PersistenceUnitUtil unitUtil = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();

Assert.assertTrue(unitUtil.isLoaded(myclassInstance));

Assert.assertFalse(unitUtil.isLoaded(myclassInstance, "myChildObjectList")); //for object collections
```